# SQL Server pyodbc large text insertion issue

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a large string text to be inserted into a column in SQL Server 2014 Express (v12.0.2000). Initially I defined the field as `text` type and the data was inserted into the table without any issues. Later I found out that the `text` datatype is deprecated and not supposed to be used. Converting the datatype to `varchar(max)` started a weird issue in pyodbc. When the same data is inserted to the `varchar(max)` column, it throws an error with the following message:

> [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Warning: Partial insert/update. The insert/update of a text or image column(s) did not succeed. (0) (SQLPutData)

but the same insertion works fine with the `text` column.

I was using `{SQL Server}` driver with windows authentication, when I changed it to `{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}` it started to fail in authentication, so I switched it back to `{SQL Server}` as it was working with the `text` data type.

I looked into some of the discussion regarding similar issues, but could not find a case that helps in debugging the issue.

I checked the sizes of strings where the data is successfully inserted and failed:

- `TEXT`: all data inserted successfully.
- `VARCHAR(MAX)`: string with length 98566 inserts but with length 326235 fails.

Any guidance even debug tips will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no difference in the use of these types. Nor does the native client have authentication issues. Millions of peoples would have noticed *that* one a decade ago. Post your code and the actual, full errors

Comment: Authentication issues would have been noticed by *every* developer on Windows since .NET 1.0 came out in 2002. The move from `text` to `varchar(max)` came in 2005. Randomly switching drivers can only *introduce* errors, not fix them

Comment: I assume the language you use is Python. What *library* did you use? Did you check any examples that deal with BLOB/CLOB data for that library?

Comment: I am sorry @PanagiotisKanavos , I messed it up as you would have expected. With pyodbc and native driver 11.0, we need to explicitly mention trusted connection for windows authentication, which was not he case for the earlier one. Also, pyodbc takes Trusted_Connection='yes' instead of Trusted_Connection=true. These are the reason why I was getting the authentication issue. Got it resolved anyway.

Comment: However, I the issue regarding {SQL Server} and varchar(max) datatype I mentioned is still there, even though I got the working alternate now. Should I post more info on the issue in case you want to look into it? I was using pyodbc library for database connectivity. @PanagiotisKanavos  thanks for your quick response bdw. :)

Answer (score 4):

The "Warning: Partial insert/update." error is related to

- the ancient `DRIVER=SQL Server` ODBC driver (SQLSRV32.DLL),
- `[n]varchar(max)` columns, and
- strings longer than 204800 characters.

It does not occur with newer drivers like `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server` or `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`.

You should update your driver and then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if the authentication error persists and you need help with that.